# Share cookies created in one and using it in another Using Cookie Authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity in asp.net core mvc 2.0?

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

### Application 1:

**StartUp.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();                
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie((options) =>
    {
       options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";
       options.Cookie.Name = "mycookie";
       options.Cookie.Path = "/";
       options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
       options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Lax;
   });          
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{     
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Accounts}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, authUserNameBuilder.ToString())
};

var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
    CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
    new AuthenticationProperties{
        IsPersistent = false
    }
);
```

## Application 2:

---

**StartUp.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie((options) =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Domain = "localhost";
        options.Cookie.Name = "mycookie";
        options.Cookie.Path = "/";
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Lax;
    });          
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{     
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Accounts}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
foreach (var claims in HttpContext.User.Claims)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(claims.Value);
}
```

In Controller.cs of Application 1, I am creating Cookies using Cookies Authentication as shown in code.

In Application 1 and Application 2, Startup.cs is same.

In Controller.cs of Application 2, I am trying to get Cookies as created in Application 1 using For Loop as shown in code.

But I am unable to get cookies in Application 2 created in Application1. Please Suggest.

Reference : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: I am referring https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Perhaps this may help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/security/cookie-sharing?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x